# How to show HTTP response in alert window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, response

Having trouble showing the JSON response using `window.alert` or `alert` in JavaScript. I'm not a native JS coder, I apologize for the noobness. Below are a few examples I've tried based on examples I found online.

My goal is to have the JSON response appear in an alert popup window.

```
# example 1
<script type="text/javascript">
var client = new HttpClient();
client.get('https://website.com/json/', function(response) {
    window.alert(response);
});
</script>

# example 2
$.get('https://website.com/json/', function(responseText) {
    alert(responseText);
});


# example 3
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
$.get('https://website.com/json/', function(responseText) {
    alert(responseText);
});
</script>

# example 4
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://website.com/json/", true);
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

function processRequest(e) {

}
```

Comment: Example two works for me using `https://stackoverflow.com` . Check the console for errors. It is possible you're getting a cross origin request error for requesting https from http or something

Comment: Assuming the cross-domain calls you're making are to domains which include CORS headers in the response (which is a little unlikely) then what you have should work. To help debug this I would suggest first checking the console for errors after making any requests (pressing F12 in your browser should open the dev console). Also, use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. Alerting debug information is a bad idea as it coerces all data types to a string, so what you see may not be what you actually have.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem that I can see is that the url https://website.com/json does not have a correct response.

you can for example try these links: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
or https://ipinfo.io/json

I prove your example 4 and it work perfectly.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", true);
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

function processRequest(e) {
   var response=JSON.stringify(e);
   alert(response);
}
```

you can notice that I put the alert in the processRequest function and before display it. I used JSON.stringify to change the object e to a string. Let me knoe if that work for you.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to display object in alert it will say [Object object]. Your response is a JSON. Stringify it, so that alert can display it.

```
$.get('https://website.com/json/', function(responseText) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(responseText));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample code on jsfiddle for your scenario:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      } 
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ashvinimaurya/kn3yv7Lh/7/

I'm making an ajax call and then alerting the response data after stringifying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting cors error, (cross origin error). You should set your request headers correctly according to the third party (https://website.com/json/) server headers.